# What is a right way to initialize fields in Spring Beans?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, in-class-initialization

I'm wondering how should I initialize fields in Spring Beans? Here is several possible solutions:

**1. Initialize fields directly on declaration**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DeclarationInit {

    private final int field = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

**2. Initialize fields using `@Value` annotation**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ValueInit {

    @Value("#{T(Integer).MAX_VALUE}")
    private int field;

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

**3. Initialize fields using `@Autowired` annotation**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AutowiredInit {

    private int field;

    @Autowired
    private void initField() {
        field = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

**4. Initialize fields using `@PostConstruct` annotation**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PostConstructInit {

    private int field;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initField() {
        field = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

All tests succeeds and do not show any difference:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SomeTestContextConfiguration.class)
public class FieldInitTest {

    @Autowired
    private DeclarationInit declarationInit;

    @Autowired
    private ValueInit valueInit;

    @Autowired
    private AutowiredInit autowiredInit;

    @Autowired
    private PostConstructInit postConstructInit;

    @Test
    public void shouldInitializeFieldOnDeclaration() {
        assertThat(declarationInit.getField(), equalTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitializeFieldWithValueAnnotation() {
        assertThat(valueInit.getField(), equalTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitializeFieldWithAutowiredSetter() {
        assertThat(autowiredInit.getField(), equalTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInitializeFieldWithPostConstruct() {
        assertThat(postConstructInit.getField(), equalTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }
}
```

Are this declarations equal to each other or should I use only one of them or neither of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the value is a constant, the **first option** is the simplest to understand and works without Spring, simplifying unit testing.

The **second and fourth options** are more complex and introduce an unnecessary dependency on the Spring container without any benefit.

The **third option** is outright bizarre, since you're using `@Autowired` and not performing dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

I believe spring offers all those options because you might run into different requirements...

1. If you want `MAX_INT` and there's no way on earth anyone needs to initialize it differently, then it's enough to declare `int field = Integer.MAX_INT` regardless of Spring.
2. If you do want to allow other initial configurations, then you can initialize it using `@Autowired`, or through a constructor arg, or setter/getter... it's a matter of taste.
3. `@PostConstruct` is more suitable for complex situations, e.g. if your field needs to be calculated based on other injected fields.